# "Open with..." issue if app is not already open

Tags: ios, objective-c, appdelegate, ios6.1

My app can read .txt files opened with the "open with..." dialog. I implemented my read functions in both the

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

and

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

methods.

The interesting thing is that it appears to only work if the app was previously open. If I open a .txt file in i.e. Mail and select "open with" then my app. I can see in the console, that the

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

gets called. I can also see the URL to the correct file which is supposably in

> file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/F15C57D0-4F62-4979-943A-2D387488D59C/Documents/Inbox/myFile.txt

But when I try to open the file I get a Cocoa error that the files does not exist.

If I repeat the steps (with the app open in the background) than the file is found and it works immediately. 
Why is this?

Comment: Are you referring to the url of the `openUrl:url` or the value designated by the key `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` in the options dictionary of `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`?

Comment: If your app wasn't already running, you will receive an `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` message with the URL in the options dictionary, and then you will **also** receive an `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` message.  Make sure you're not deleting the file in the first method and then expecting it to still be around when the second is called.

Comment: that was probably the problem. I was deleting the file after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `application:openURL` was then not finding anything. I now am only dealing with the file in `application:openURL` and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Thanks @rob mayoff. This was indeed the case for me as well. I was deleting the file during the cleanup on launch.

Answer (score 4):

You should handle the case only in `application:openUrl:sourceApplication:annotations`. According to documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:):

> If your app had to be launched to open the URL, the app calls the `application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` methods first, followed by this method. The return values of those methods can be used to prevent this method from being called. (If the app is already running, only this method is called.)

So, there is no need to handle opening files in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` anymore.

Comment: Exactly what I needed to know, the order of method calls, which I couldn't find elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You should be handling the "Open with.." during `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` by getting the URL from `options` dictionary with the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` key - not the `url` directly passed in `application:openUrl:sourceApplication:annotations`.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/OpeningSupportedFileTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010412-SW1

Comment: But how do I then handle calls to an app already open in the background? `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` doesn't get called again, right?